# Sql showing results that are zero

Tags: sql

i am using this query to search from my site.

```
SELECT A.article_title , 
( 
  (CASE WHEN A.article_title LIKE '%earn%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
+ ( CASE WHEN A.article_title LIKE '%facebook%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )) AS count 
FROM site_articles A
A.article_id ORDER BY count DESC
```

it showing me the flowing results..

```
article_title                           count
Earn From facebook                        2
Earn From adsense                         1
how to work online                        0
making money tips                         0
```

It's also showing the results that have '0' count.

how i can prevent from it.

Comment: Just modify your select statement to say something along the lines of this pseudo SQL:    where count(*) > 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just exclude these rows in the `WHERE` and don't count them at all.

```
SELECT A.article_title,
       ( ( CASE
             WHEN A.article_title LIKE '%earn%' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END ) + ( CASE
                       WHEN A.article_title LIKE '%facebook%' THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                     END ) ) AS count
FROM   site_articles A
WHERE  A.article_title LIKE '%earn%'
        OR A.article_title LIKE '%facebook%'
ORDER  BY count DESC
```

Or an alternative that may be less efficient but more maintainable would be to put the query in a derived table

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT A.article_title,
               ( ( CASE
                     WHEN A.article_title LIKE '%earn%' THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                   END ) + ( CASE
                               WHEN A.article_title LIKE '%facebook%' THEN 1
                               ELSE 0
                             END ) ) AS Count
        FROM   site_articles A) T
WHERE  T.Count > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
SELECT A.article_title , 
( 
  (CASE WHEN A.article_title LIKE '%earn%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
+ ( CASE WHEN A.article_title LIKE '%facebook%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )) AS count 
FROM site_articles A
A.article_id HAVING count>0 ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: This use of referring to newly-defined-in-`SELECT` columns in the `HAVING` clause is also specific to MySQL. Other database systems can give an error about an invalid column name "count".

Comment: Hm, I can use aliases in `HAVING` in normal SQL - if they're defined in main `SELECT` statement. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: This is [an optional MySQL extension](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50448) not standard SQL.

Comment: A quick test on SQLFiddle shows that at least MSSQL, Oracle and PostgreSQL don't like it. SQLite is even worse and doesn't accept `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` at all.

Comment: Yes - got it now. It's an __aggregate__ column. So you're right